# In a given set of data, how do I calculate the first percentile using interpolation?

Tags: probability, statistics, interpolation

our class was given a set of data where we were tasked to find the first percentile using interpolation. The given set of data is as follows (in billion of dollars):

18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 32,
33, 49, 52, 56

We were taught to use the formula k(n+1)/100 where K = kth percentile, which in this case is 1, and where n = no. of data which is 20, and solving this gives you the percentile's location. But, when I solved it, it gives me 0.21, which isn't a whole number, so how do I solve this?

Much thanks in advance,
R.

Comment: What does it _mean_ to ask "What is the lowest percent?" when there are only $20$ observations?

Answer (score 0):

You got 0.21. We count it to nearest whole number.

So, we count up one number.  So, we get 18.

You can look [Similar example here finding 3rd percentile.](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/find-50th-percentile-3rd-percentile-and-33rd-469892)